# Changing the Color of a div

Tags: javascript

I have two div elements, with different colors, the first one have for example red color and the second one have blue color, so now, I want to change the color of div with red to blue color, so how could I do it with javascript?

Comment: this type of question has been asked before. Do some research in SO and elsewhere to find the direction to take. This forum exists to help people whi have tried and not succeeded, rather than to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

here you go: if you want to animate the change, do it in css
https://jsfiddle.net/5tbfw1wu/

```
document.getElementById("toRed").style.backgroundColor  = "red";
```